# delete folders with the same name as the parent folders recursively in bash?

Tags: linux, bash, scripting, terminal

Some file copying went wrong in one of my machines and I'm wasting a ludicrous amount of space by having a copy of each folder inside of the parent with the same name, and I want to delete them all.

Example:

```
 /mnt/test/files/foo
 \_ /mnt/test/files/foo/file1 (etc)
 |__ /mnt/test/files/foo/foo
 \_ /mnt/test/files/foo/foo/file1 (etc)
 |_ /mnt/files/foo/foo2
  \_ /mnt/files/foo/foo2/file1 (etc)
 |_ /mnt/files/foo/foo2/foo2
  \_ /mnt/files/foo/foo2/foo2/file1 (etc)
```

So obviously I want to delete `/mnt/files/foo/foo`, `/mnt/files/foo/foo2/foo2` and its contents (and so on) entirely and stop wasting space. What would be a good way to script it in bash?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If your `find` supports the `-regex` predicate, you can list the directories with:

```
find . -type d -regex '.*/\([^/]*\)/\1' -prune -print
```

to remove them, you can change `-print` to:

```
-exec rm -rf {} +
```

But be sure to check the list first so you don't delete any files you need.

Answer (score 0):

Using non-GNU `find` (but still some implementation that supports `-mindepth`, such as `find` on BSD systems):

```
find top-dir -depth -mindepth 1 -type d -exec sh -c '
    for pathname do
        subdir=$pathname/${pathname##*/}
        if [ -d "$subdir" ]; then
            printf "Would remove directory %s\n" "$subdir"
            # rm -rfi "$subdir"
        fi
    done' sh {} +
```

This would do a depth-first traversal of the directory hierarchy rooted at `top-dir`.  For batches of found directory pathnames, a short shell script would be called.  In each iteration of the loop in the short shell script, the pathname for a subdirectory within the `$pathname` directory that has the same name as the directory itself is constructed.  If that subdirectory exists, it is reported (the deletion is currently commented out for safety).

The `-depth` option causes a depth-first traversal.  This is usually what you want when you delete directories with `find` as `find` would otherwise potentially try to enter directories that you have already deleted.

The `-mindepth 1` option ensures that the top directory is not deleted, as it would be would you use `.` as the start search path.

Related:

- [Understanding the -exec option of `find`](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/389705/understanding-the-exec-option-of-find)